# Как установить GRUB в FreeBSD 13.1?

Tags: grub, freebsd

- ОС - FreeBSD 13.1, amd64
- Система - BIOS/Legacy Boot

Разбил диск так:

```
/dev/ada0 - BSD
/dev/ada0a - ufs - /boot - 512M
/dev/ada0b - ufs - / - 15.8G
```

Система установилась, но вообще не загружается. Разбивал диск так:

```
root@freebsd-iso: ~ # gpart create -s BSD /dev/ada0
root@freebsd-iso: ~ # gpart add -t freebsd-ufs -s 512M /dev/ada0
root@freebsd-iso: ~ # gpart add -t freebsd-ufs /dev/ada0
root@freebsd-iso: ~ # newfs -U /dev/ada0a
root@freebsd-iso: ~ # newfs -U /dev/ada0b
root@freebsd-iso: ~ # mount /dev/ada0b /mnt
root@freebsd-iso: ~ # mkdir -p /mnt/boot
root@freebsd-iso: ~ # mount /dev/ada0a /mnt/boot
```

Поставил систему, а VirtualBox в упор не видит установленную BSD:

```
No bootable medium found! System halted!
```

Да и чёрт бы со стоковым загрузчиком, ибо мне нужен GRUB... Ага, щас.

Загружаюсь с Linux Lite. `fdisk` то видит, что перед ним BSD диск, а вот как смонтировать `/dev/sda` (у меня только `/dev/sda` и отображается, никаких `/dev/sda1` или `/dev/sdaa`) - без понятия. Ну и смонтировал "в лоб":

```
root@linuxlite6-iso: ~ # mount -t ufs -o type=ufs2 /dev/sda /target
```

Смонтировался именно boot раздел. Было бы прекрасно, если бы не одно но: boot смонтировался в READ-ONLY. Так что GRUB не поставить.

Пытаюсь зайти в chroot и из портов поставить GRUB. pkg не устанавливается: не работает интернет, даже ping по ip:

```
root@freebsd-iso: ~ # mount /dev/ada0b /mnt
root@freebsd-iso: ~ # mount /dev/ada0a /mnt/boot
root@freebsd-iso: ~ # mount_nullfs /dev /mnt/dev
root@freebsd-iso: ~ # mount_nullfs /proc /mnt/proc
root@freebsd-iso: ~ # chroot /mnt
root@freebsd: ~ # pkg
# Предлагает установить pkg из-за его отсутствия в системе
root@freebsd: ~ # ping 8.8.8.8
No route to host
root@freebsd: ~ # cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
root@freebsd: ~ # cat /etc/rc.conf
clear_tmp_enable="yes"
syslogd_flags="-ss"
sendmail_enable="NONE"
hostname="localhost"
ifconfig_em0="DHCP"
ifconfig_em0_ipv6="inet6 accept_rtadv"
dumpdev="AUTO"
```

Ну и как туда GRUB поставить? Есть ещё мысль переразбить диск в MBR или APM, но, боюсь, проблему не решит.